# Angular Async Form Validator - How to Await response from getDistanceMatrix call back

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

I have a reactive form with a deliveryAddress field that has a custom async validator. I use google places API to check distance.

However, the API requires a callback to get the response. This causes a problem in my async validator because I don't know how to get the response from the call back to the outer function.

I use the response to parse distance in the callback. Based on the distance the field is valid or invalid.

Documentation for Google Maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results).

```
this.orderObject = this.fb.group({
  deliveryAddress: ['', [Validators.required], this.validDeliveryAddress.bind(this)]
});

async validDeliveryAddress(control: AbstractControl) {

  const origin2 = this.restaurantAddress;
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  let resp = await service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin2],
    destinations: [control.value],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    // HERE HOW TO GET response IN OUTER LAYER AFTER DONE EXECUTING?
  }, async(response, status) => {
    resp = await this.handleMapResponse(response, status);
    console.log('resp', resp);
    return resp;
  });

  console.log('resp', resp);

  // end outer function
}


// CALL BACK FUNCTION HERE
async handleMapResponse(response, status): Promise < any > {

  let from;
  let to;
  let duration;
  let distance: string;

  // if true, means not a valid address sent yet
  if (response.destinationAddresses.includes('')) {
    console.log('not valid addresss yet')
    return {
      validAddress: true
    };
  }

  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    console.log('status ok');
    let origins = response.originAddresses;
    let destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    console.log('origins', origins);
    console.log('destinations', destinations);
    for (let i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      let results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        let element = results[j];
        distance = element.distance.text;
        duration = element.duration.text;
        from = origins[i];
        to = destinations[j];
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('not ok', status);
  }
  console.log('from', from);
  console.log('to', to);
  console.log('distance', distance);
  console.log('duration', duration);

  if (distance.includes("ft")) {
    return {
      'validAddress': true
    }
  } else if (parseFloat(distance) <= 3) {
    return {
      'validAddress': true
    }
  } else {
    return {
      'validAddress': true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure why you've made `handleMapResponse` `async`. It's getting called synchronously anyway. Plus it's task is to determine whether you need to show an error or not. Could you please share your implementation of `service.getDistanceMatrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just turn the response into a Promise and await that.

```
async validDeliveryAddress(control: AbstractControl) {
  const origin2 = this.restaurantAddress;
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  const {response, status} = await new Promise(resolve => 
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin2],
      destinations: [control.value],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    }, (response, status) => resolve({response, status}))
  );

  const resp = await this.handleMapResponse(response, status);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, that worked!
Though, I don't quite understand the syntax. Can you help me understand? 

1) Why we need const { response, status } =  ... ?
Is it just a place holder? Can we do it with just await new Promise(resolve => ... ?

2) Is the const { response, status } what is sent in this line?
    const resp = await this.handleMapResponse(response, status);

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, when calling `resolve`, i pass in an object `{response, status}`, which is shorthand for `{response: response, status: status}`. That is the return value of the await. Usually, you would write: `const returnedObj = await new Promise....; const response = returnedObj.response; const status = returnedObj.status`. The destructuring syntax `const {response, status} = await new Promise...` does exactly that.